# PHP video snapshot display

Tags: php

Is there any way to display video(snapshot) as as a image in PHP?

Comment: You've mistaken, pal. PHP is a Hypertext preprocessor, not video editor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create thumbnails or preview for videos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265572/how-to-create-thumbnails-or-preview-for-videos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well You can create thumbnail using **ffmpeg** .

Then you can simply execute that command from php using exec. You can show created thumbnail then as you want.

You can check
http://flowplayer.org/tutorials/generating-thumbs.html

Answer (score 2):

There is an option without generating a new snapshot, simply using html code :) easy, isn't it?

```
<video src='DIRECCION_DEL_VIDEO' width='100px' height='60px'/>
```

Hope you enjoy it!

Regards,

[Jose Romero](http://joseromero.me)