# How can we get the screenshot of the video in html5 using canvas

Tags: javascript

Hello is it possible to capture screenshot of the video being played using html 5 canvas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it is possible here: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/